# putting conditional logic in angular template

Tags: angularjs

This seems a little arduous to me. Looking for opinions on whether this the "best" way to do it.

I have a field in a row of a table. The value comes from the API, and I am to display 
- the appropriate icon, 
- in the appropriate colour, 
- with the appropriate title text.

Is there a more succinct way of doing this? Should I be doing this logic in the template? Should this be handled in the controller, or the directive?

```
<div class="ngCellText">
    <span
        ng-class="{
            'icon-default':!row.entity[col.field],
            'icon-done':row.entity[col.field] == 'AVAILABLE',
            'icon-warning':row.entity[col.field] == 'PROCESSING',
            'icon-default':row.entity[col.field] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE'
        }"

        title= "{{row.entity[col.field] == 'AVAILABLE' ? 'Available' : ''}}{{ row.entity[col.field] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE' ? 'Not Available' : ''}}{{ row.entity[col.field] == 'PROCESSING' ? 'Processing' : ''}}{{ !row.entity[col.field] ? 'Unknown' : ''}}">
        <i
            class="fa"
            ng-class="{
                'fa-check-square-o':row.entity[col.field] == 'AVAILABLE',
                'fa-times':row.entity[col.field] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE',
                'fa-clock-o':row.entity[col.field] == 'PROCESSING',
                'fa-question':!row.entity[col.field]}">
        </i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i would say create a directive

Comment: I just stumbled upon ng-switch.

Comment: you can use ng-switch but it clutters your html, and your html is no longer readable/understandable :( and you loose testability

Answer (score 0):

How about just having your class be a function call and do the logic in there.

```
     <li ng-class="computeClass()">


     $scope.computeClass = function() {
      // Put your logic to build your comma sep class string
        var ret = "AVAILABLE";
        return ret;
     };
```